# IE Width Rendering issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, chromium

I've designed a fixed-width page which renders equally in Chromium, Firefox, Safari, but has a small issue in (from what I can tell) ALL flavours of IE.  I've added some conditional styles for IE, which make things a bit better, but it's still off (by only a couple of pixels).

The site in question is here: http://www.brushesfacepainting.co.uk/brushes/home

IE and Chromium rendering side by side is shown here:  http://www.brushesfacepainting.co.uk/images/renderissue.jpg

I added conditional styles for IE to fix the width of all the elements, prior to this, the banner style was much narrower than the body.

I assume I'm hitting up against an IE bug, but I can't figure out which one!  Can anyone help please?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mainbodyie` rule has a width that is different than the width in your standard css. (851px vs 848px). Fix that to match your other wrappers.

Also your page is not centered in IE - I suggest you wrap whole page in a fixed width wrapper with margin:0 auto to center whole page - so you don't keep repeating the width multiple times in your css for each layout element.

Comment: You're right, but that was just part of my hacking.  I've now removed the fixed widths from the IE conditional.  Also, the body style is fixed width with margin: 10px auto.  IE still looks the same - it seems to be ignoring the auto horizontal margin.

Comment: @Lee - You might be hitting the double margin bug in IE. Try removing the `margin-left:20px;` from `.tabcontent` and put it on `div-nav` as margin-right. Left floated element can get it's left margin doubled in ie in certain occasions.

Comment: It's partly fixed now, with hints from your post and kapillohakare, so thanks for your help.  I had all the width contraints in the body.  I've switched it to a div sitting inside the body, and that has helped.  The only issue remaining is that IE seems to be ignoring the auto (horiz) margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* ONLY FOR IE */

DIV.mainbodyie{
  width: 848px;
}

DIV.mainbody{
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a div structure for enclosing all content like header,middle,footer inside it.Add following code for this div:

```
.test{
overflow:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I've done this, and it certainly has helped (the offset issue on the right has gone away) - thanks very much.  The only remaining issue is that IE seems to be ignoring the auto horiz margin.

Comment: Try this :left: 50%;
margin-left: -380px;

Comment: Solved the margin issue.  My doctype declaration was incorrect so IE was going into quirks mode, and hence ignoring the auto margin.